# Info Web Page For Raspberry Pi Application

Tags: java, javascript, raspberry-pi

I have an application running on rPi2. Which reads sensor values and logs them with Time marks on file(written in java). I need to setup a webpage to show these logs. Since Pi will be a headless, i decided to go with webpage way. I picked charts.js as chart drawing library. And it accepts chart data like this :

```
var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6,7,8,9]
            }
        ]

    }
```

I need to change data and labels values on JSON programatically. And serve this page to local network. I tried to generate my Log with this JSON format but turns out JS cannot load Local File without a user picking a file from dialog. So any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cool project. I did the following:

tmp_data.txt (generated via java on the raspi after measurements):

```
{"labels" : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    "datasets" : [
        {
            "label": "My First dataset",
            "fillColor" : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            "strokeColor" : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "pointColor" : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "pointStrokeColor" : "#fff",
            "pointHighlightFill" : "#fff",
            "pointHighlightStroke" : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "data" : [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6,5]
        }
    ]
}
```

tmp_data.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                var lineChartData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {responsive: true});
              }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","tmp_data.txt",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

</head>
    <body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
        <div style="width:30%">
            <div>
                <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'fields' in the data file has to be surrounded with quotes. The onload function is called when the site is loaded. The txt file will be read via a httprequest and has to be in the same directory as the html page. I would recommend that some webserver on the raspi will deliver the html.
As far as i know js cannot load a local file on the client without user interaction because this could be a serious security issue.